# NodeJS Thousands of GET Requests

Tags: node.js, polling

I'm currently exploring ideas for writing a NodeJS app that does the following

1. Get URLs from iOS app and store them in a DB (completed)
2. Poll each URL from the above Array of URLs every few seconds. (I know how this is implemented).
3. Each such URL returns a JSON formatted object from which I will construct a Push Notification and send it to that device.

I've read a few articles that explain how to implement polling of a resource. However, I haven't come across anything that explains how to do that for serval thousand resources.

Here's my question:

A. How does one run several such HTTP requests simultaneously?

B. What factors need to be considered in terms of performance, networking and so on (with respect to the polling of URLs only)?

C. What's the best approach for doing the above polling? Should I be employing child_process.fork() or something entirely different and more performant?

Kindly assume the following restriction for sake of discussion: I'll b running all this on a single EC2 medium instance.

Hoping for some good solutions. Cheers.